# Ruby cURL POST Request not going through

Tags: ruby, json, post, curl, bamboo

I am using Paw, an application to test REST requests. I have the follow request working using the application but need to change it to use cURL to use in my ruby on rails application.

`POST /rest/api/latest/result/TRUNKDEVQAUNIT-TESTANDRGITBUILDDEV-12/comment HTTP/1.1
Content-type: application/json
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Basic dWkud29ya2JvdDpFVmgzUFQ0dEch
Cookie: JSESSIONID=C851F60AFB4A83F12753B9CCBC745093
Host: bamboo10.com
Connection: close
User-Agent: Paw/2.2.5 (Macintosh; OS X/10.10.5) GCDHTTPRequest
Content-Length: 32`

`{"content":"here is a comment, for testing purposes“}`

I think it should look something like this but it is not working. I did not add the real username and password (or host) in for security reasons. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

`curl -X POST -u username:password --data {"body": "This is a comment, for testing purposes"} -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" [https://bamboo.com/rest/api/latest/result/TRUNKDEVQAUNIT-TESTANDRGITBUILDDEV-12/comment`](https://bamboo.com/rest/api/latest/result/TRUNKDEVQAUNIT-TESTANDRGITBUILDDEV-12/comment%60)

Comment: what is the output you are getting?

Comment: Finally got it working, thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little time, I found the correct way to do it. It appears I was missing a ' before and after the data, as well as changing the json element to be `content` and not `body`

`curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -u username:password -d '{"content": "This is a comment, for testing purposes"}' https://bamboo10.com/rest/api/latest/result/TRUNKDEVQAUNIT-TESTANDRGITBUILDDEV-12/comment`